# Optimize query execution based on two datetime columns

Tags: mysql

I've been struggling all day long against this.

We have a very busy database (still on development) and we have records being inserted very frequently. The record logs have a start time and a end time.

If I want to select something between `col1`(`datetime`) and `col2`(`datetime`) MySQL can't use indexes properly because it will search the index for `col1` but will never look into `col2`.
The database engine is InnoDB. What happens is for example that MySQL will search 80 thousand rows when the interval requested should only return two rows.

My biggest problem is that I'm trying to do some aggregate functions on this time ranges and its taking a very long time when it should be really fast considering how many rows it is actually counting.

Also note that I can't do `dateStart between col1 and col2` nor `dateEnd between col1 and col2` because `dateStart` can be lower than `col1` and `dateEnd` can also be lower than `col2`.

Lets assume this sample data:

```
     col1      |     col2
---------------+---------------
date 10:20:00  |date 10:21:00
date 10:21:00  |date 10:22:00
date 10:22:00  |date 10:23:00
date 10:23:00  |date 10:24:00
date 10:24:00  |date 10:25:00
date 10:25:00  |date 10:26:00
date 10:26:00  |date 10:27:00
```

If I need the rows that range between 10:21:30 and 10:25:30 I need to do something like this:

```
'10:25:30' <= col1 AND '10:21:30' >= col2.
```

So how do I index these columns properly? MySQL only picks up one of the date columns in the index.

Comment: Can the intervals `(col1, col2)` be overlapping or not?

Comment: I had a similar question once for postgres and at that time a solution was to use geometric types. The basic principal is to convert the ranges to boxes and then query for overlapping boxes. It is not as efficient as having real range types (postgresql has them since 9.2)  but it was at least reasonable fast.

Comment: @ypercube col1 and col2 can be the same value for one row but col1 and col2 don't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who took the time to respond.
I got it fixed in a different way.
Since the values can't overlap and mysql is efficient using one single index for ranges, what i did was find the first col1 and last col1 and use a select between. This turned out really fast because mysql now analyses only the lines in the range.

As for the aggregates which were causing problems I still had to go round them anyways because I had to execute it separately or otherwise MySQL optimizer was really inefficient. The way I did it was by selecting the results into a temporary memory table and then loop those results (cursor wasn't a choice because I already had a loop) and doing the 3 aggregate functions at once. This is was the final result (just the loop part):

myLoop: LOOP

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT
    @CarrId := carrier_id,
    @FistVTime := firstValidTIME,
    @LastVTime := lastValidTIME
FROM startStopReportTable
WHERE maxSpeed = -1) AS dummyTbl) < 1 THEN
    LEAVE myLoop;
END IF;

UPDATE startStopReportTable AS t0,
    (SELECT
        SUM(l0.distance) AS distance,
        AVG(l0.speed) AS avgspeed,
        MAX(l0.speed) AS maxspeed
        FROM
            pcoarg AS l0
        WHERE
            l0.carrier_id = @CarrId
        AND
            l0.lastValidTIME BETWEEN @FistVTime AND @LastVTime
    ) AS t1
SET
    t0.distance = t1.distance,
    t0.averageSpeed = t1.avgspeed,
    t0.maxSpeed = t1.maxspeed
WHERE t0.carrier_id = @CarrId AND t0.firstValidTIME = @FistVTime AND t0.lastValidTIME = @LastVTime;
END LOOP;
```

LastValidTIME is col1
startStopReportTable is temporary table

Profiling results:

```
96  0.00058100  UPDATE startStopReportTable AS t0,
      (SELECT
       SUM(l0.distance) AS distance,
       AVG(l0.speed) AS avgspeed,
       MAX(l0.speed) AS maxspeed
       FROM
        pcoarg AS l0
       WHERE
        l0.carrier_id = @CarrId
       AND
        l0.lastValidTI...
97  0.00045100  UPDATE startStopReportTable AS t0,
      (SELECT
       SUM(l0.distance) AS distance,
       AVG(l0.speed) AS avgspeed,
       MAX(l0.speed) AS maxspeed
       FROM
        pcoarg AS l0
       WHERE
        l0.carrier_id = @CarrId
       AND
        l0.lastValidTI...
98  0.00094900  UPDATE startStopReportTable AS t0,
      (SELECT
       SUM(l0.distance) AS distance,
       AVG(l0.speed) AS avgspeed,
       MAX(l0.speed) AS maxspeed
       FROM
        pcoarg AS l0
       WHERE
        l0.carrier_id = @CarrId
       AND
        l0.lastValidTI...
```

It's really a shame that the optimizer can't combine sub query aggregates in one query while it can combine them in one query.